# multiple-value .Exec() in single-value context with Golang sql

Tags: sql, sqlite, go

I am trying to update multiple values in a single row in an SQLite3 database using golang and the standard sql driver but am having trouble debugging the following error:

```
 command-line-arguments
./server.go:169: multiple-value updateStatement.Exec() in single-value context
```

The relevant code is as follows (irrelevant code has been omitted):

SQL Statement:

```
const (
    rsvpSubmit = "UPDATE rsvp SET Name = ?, Rsvp = ?, Guests = ?, Meal0 = ?, Meal1 = ?, Comments = ?, ModifiedAt = ? WHERE email = ?"
)

var (
    updateStatement *sql.Stmt
)

errr := updateStatement.Exec(
    r.FormValue("name"),
    r.FormValue("rsvp"),
    r.FormValue("guests"),
    r.FormValue("meal0"),
    r.FormValue("meal1"),
    r.FormValue("comments"),
    time.Now(),
    cookie.Value)
```

The database has the following columns (which the struct replicates):

```
    type User struct {
        Id         int
        Email      string
        Name       sql.NullString
        Rsvp       sql.NullInt64
        Guests     sql.NullInt64
        Meal0      sql.NullString
        Meal1      sql.NullString
        Comments   sql.NullString
        ModifiedAt sql.NullString
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Stmt.Exec`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Stmt.Exec) is defined as:

```
func (s *Stmt) Exec(args ...interface{}) (Result, error)
```

if you don't care about the result then you can use `_, err := updateStatement.Exec(...)`